# Excecive memory usage after changing Coherence configuration

Tags: java, caching, out-of-memory, weblogic12c, oracle-coherence

We changed the Coherence cache from "replicated" to "near-distributed-persistent", but now the servers get overloaded.

This is the current configuration:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<cache-config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-cache-config"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-cache-config">
  <caching-scheme-mapping>
    <cache-mapping>
      <cache-name>app-*</cache-name>
      <scheme-name>app-refdata-near</scheme-name>
    </cache-mapping>
    <cache-mapping>
      <cache-name>configConsultationCache</cache-name>
      <scheme-name>config</scheme-name>
    </cache-mapping>
  </caching-scheme-mapping>

  <caching-schemes>
    <near-scheme>
      <scheme-name>app-refdata-near</scheme-name>
      <front-scheme>
        <local-scheme>
          <scheme-ref>app-refdata-local</scheme-ref>
        </local-scheme>
      </front-scheme>
      <back-scheme>
        <distributed-scheme>
          <scheme-ref>partitioned</scheme-ref>
        </distributed-scheme>
      </back-scheme>
    </near-scheme>

    <local-scheme>
      <scheme-name>app-refdata-local</scheme-name>
    </local-scheme>

    <distributed-scheme>
      <scheme-name>partitioned</scheme-name>
      <backup-count>2</backup-count>
      <backing-map-scheme>
        <local-scheme/>
      </backing-map-scheme>
      <persistence>
        <environment>default-active</environment>
      </persistence>
      <autostart>true</autostart>
    </distributed-scheme>

    <local-scheme>
      <scheme-name>config</scheme-name>
      <expiry-delay>1h</expiry-delay>
    </local-scheme>
  </caching-schemes>

</cache-config>
```

Which, by the way, is duplicated: is present in 2 jar, but under the same deployable ear.

In the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/coherence/12.2.1.4/administer/persisting-caches.html#GUID-1848628D-5423-4167-93F0-61196B4C35FE), it is specified that for active-persistent mode, an additional allocation of 20-35% more memory is recommended, which has already been done.

Each node has approximately 50g of physical memory available, and we have set the heap size between -Xmx=32g and -Xms=32g, but even with that, the memory usage reaches more than 90% of the total available.

On a nightly basis, the application refreshes the content of the cache.

It has been noticed that the overload becomes more pronounced when the application is used intensively (it's a high-throughput type of application), as a result, the cache is used (read) further.

By checking the MBeans of Coherence in the Enterprise Manager, we see multiple entries for the same cache name. For instance, 3 of them are NearCache types and the other 3 are LocalCache.

We have analyzed a heap dump, but there is nothing unusual. The heap dump weighs just 9g, not 32g. The biggest objects are, as expected, from Coherence.

[image: heap dump usage]

Any advice? **Does the coherence configuration look okay? Does the refresh of the complete cache conflict with the new configuration?**

Comment: One thing that stands out is the backup count of 2.  That means for each cache entry, there will be two identical cache entries created and distributed amongst the members.  Typically a backup count of 1 is sufficient.  Is there a reason you're using 2?

Comment: @rlubke We thought 'more redundancy the better', but yes, we could try with 1 as well. Nevertheless, shouldn't this be stable and not impact the performance in such ways?

Comment: Yes, it could have an impact.  Each insert or mutation of an entry, with a backup count of 2 means that in order for the operation to return, each of the backup inserts/updates needs to be completed before being returned.  The larger the backup count, the larger the increase in latency in operations.

Comment: were you able to resolve?

Comment: We suggested to try to reduce the parallelism -20% of the application and it's being monitored. Since it was quite high. No changes in Coherence for now.